# How to add an element containing fields to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Using javascript, how can I add to an array an element which contains fields (pairs of field name and field value)?
The purpose of this is that each element will later be inserted as a row to a DB, using ajax.
Just to make sure - after the array is ready I should be able to access a field this way:

```
shopsArray[4].shopName
```

Edit:
It's working with Pointy's answer but I still have a problem:

```
shopsArray.push( { shopId: 1, shopAddress: $('#newAddress' + j).val() } );
```

The first value is inserted fine, but the second one has a problem.
If I alert `$('#newAddress' + j).val()` than I get the correct value which has been inserted in the field in the webpage.
But if I alert `shopsArray[lastElementNumber].shopAddress` than I get `undefined`.

Can you see what's the problem here?

Edit 2:
More elaborate code:

```
// save changes in main shop
shopsArray[0].shopName = $('#mainName').val();
shopsArray[0].shopAddress = $('#mainAddress').val();

// save secondary branches to array
for (var i=1; i<shopsArray.length; i++){
    shopsArray[i].shopName = $('#secondaryName' + i).val();
    shopsArray[i].shopAddress = $('#secondaryAddress' + i).val();
}

// save new branches to array
for (var j=1; j<=newshopsCounter; j++){

    var bName = $('#newName' + j).val();

    shopsArray.push({shopId: -1, userId: shopsArray[0].userId, shopName: bName, shopAddress: $('#newAddress' + j).val()});

    alert(bName);
    alert(shopArray[1].shopName);
    alert(shopsArray[1].shopId);
}
```

The first and third alerts give the correct values. The second one gives `undefined`.

Comment: What about `alert(shopsArray[shopsArray.length - 1].shopAddress)`?

Comment: I just wrote `lastElementNumber` so it's clear I'm addressing the last element. I actually write `alert(shopsArray[1].shopAddress)`.

Comment: ah. Ok.  Well, perhaps if you posted the code *around* that point where you call ".push()" the problem would be evident.  As it is, there's nothing obviously wrong with any of that code you've posted ...

Comment: @Pointy, added all the code that seems relevant. Hope it's enough.

Comment: Well, in those alerts you're referring to `shopsArray[1]`, but the ".push()" statement before that would have changed the last element - that may or may not be element 1.  Why not also add an `alert(shopsArray.length)` there?

Comment: @Pointy, you were absolutely right. It's working now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean something like

```
shopsArray.push({ shopName: "Fred", value: "Ethel" });
```

?

*edit* — now that I know that this is the sort of thing you want to do, I'll clarify.

JavaScript has an "object literal" syntax that allows objects to be created directly as values. The syntax involves a list of property names and values, with the names and values separated by a colon and each pair separated by commas.  Thus:

```
var anObject = { someProperty: "the value" };
```

creates an object with one property and assigns it to the variable "anObject". That's effectively the same as:

```
var temp = new Object();
temp["someProperty"] = "the value";
var anObject = temp;
```

The "value" part of a property in an object literal can be any expression, but the property name must be either a string constant or an identifier (and in either case, it's *treated* like a string constant).  Thus, you can create an object with a property whose value comes from calling some function:

```
var fancyObject = { "temperature": getTemperature() };
```

Object literal expressions are values, and can be used anywhere you can use an expression, including function call arguments.  Therefore, to add an object to an array, it's possible to call the array ".push()" function and use an object literal as the argument, as in the first example:

```
shopsArray.push({ shopName: "Cheese Shoppe", shopPhone: "111 222 3232" });
```

You can even include object literals *inside* another object literal, as the value of a property:

```
shopsArray.push({
  shopName: "Cheese Shoppe", 
  shopAddress: {
    street1: "207 High Street",
    street2: "No. 5",
    city: "Austin",
    state: "TX"
  }
});
```

Comment: I think so but I'm confused about `value`. If it's a field name than yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Yes ... I'll add to the answer.

Comment: @Pointy, I still have a problem though. I have no problem adding explicit values (such as a number), but I do have a problem adding the value of a field from the html. For example: `branchName: $('#newName' + j).val();` . If I alert `$('#newName' + j).val();` by itself I get the correct value. But if I alert `shopsArray[1].branchName` I get `undefined`.

Comment: If you post the code you're using to get the values from your form into an object, either in an edit to this question or another question, I (or somebody else) can probably help. It's definitely possible to do that :-)

Comment: @Pointy, I edited my question. Hope it's what you asked for. If not, let me know what's missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would simply create a hash inside an array to achieve that:

```
var shopsArray = [
  {
    shopName: 'value1'
  }, {
    shopName: 'value2'
  }
];
```

If you have an existing array, use [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
shopsArray.push({ shopName: 'value' });
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr['field_name'] = 'field_value';

//to access it on ajax

for (var i in arr){
    //field_name is in "i"
    //field_value is in arr[i]
}
```

Comment: Better to use `var arr = [];` instead of `new Array();`.  Also, in you're example, you don't need an Array instance anyway - you're treating it as a simple Object.